# "It looks like Windows didn't load correctly" after power loss

Tags: windows-10, boot

I have some computers which are acting as information displays without a mouse or keyboard attached. After a power cut, Windows 10 fails to boot. It shows a blue Recovery screen with the message "It looks like Windows didn't load correctly". Connecting a HID and using the "Restart my PC" button works fine without having to use any of the "Advanced repair options". I can also hold the power button for 5 seconds to switch the PC off, then press the power button to switch it back on.

It seems to happen every time that an unexpected power loss occurs.

I have tried using `DISM` and `chkdsk` as well as disabling fast boot but the problem persists. Is there a way to have Windows try restating automatically (or after a timeout)?

Comment: IIRC, this occurs due to a flag that is set in a specific configuration file within a subdirectory of `%WinDir%` when a dirty shutdown occurs _(this is also why after a dirty shutdown the OS should be rebooted normally to clear the flag)_; every time Windows boots, it reads this file prior to presenting the GUI for user interaction.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To avoid Windows being notified of a power-loss condition, try this:

- Run an elevated Command Prompt (CMD Run as administrator)
- In the command window, enter the following command :

  ```
  bcdedit /set {default} bootstatuspolicy ignoreshutdownfailures
  ```
- Power-off the computer brutally by disconnecting the power,
  then restart to check if the problem is now fixed.

References :

- [BCDEdit /set](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/bcdedit--set)
- [BootStatusPolicy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-embedded-unifiedwritefilter-bootstatuspolicy)

Comment: I find it interesting that "IgnoreAllFailures" is listed as the default value. Perhaps Dell change that for the image they deploy to the machines that I have. Regardless, this seems to have worked. Thank you!